# How to know which button called certain activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

For example, I have *activityMain* which contains the main logic of the Application, but it should be opened from several buttons that stored in other activities, and some activities contains multiple buttons too. And they should call *activityMain*. So i need to pass different data from db depending on which button called *activityMain*

Help please, there weren't similar topics at all.

Comment: Send some data through [intents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)  with your activity name or id

Answer (score 1):

If i Understand your question correctly, you can achieve this functionality with android jetpack navigation component. I add the link of documentation below

[Get started with the Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started?hl=en)